# How to put Banshee in manual sort mode

Tags: banshee, music, sort

i'm making a playlist for my friend's birthday.I need to sort the songs.

Answer (score 2):

If you can't sort it, then there's already a column used for sorting. Just click on the column header until the little triangle disappears (the states are "sort ascending", "sort descending", "no sorting").